# How to store session value in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express-session

I have implemented a login and logout function in nodejs.

login function,

```
sessionRouter.post("", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const {email, password} = req.body
        console.log(email,password);
        await Joi.validate({email, password}, singIn);

        const user = await User.findOne({email});
        if( user && user.comparePasswords(password)){
            const sessionUser = sessionizeUser(user);

            req.session.user = sessionUser; // here I am storing the session details in the backend
            res.send(sessionUser);
         } else {
            throw new Error('Invalid login credentials');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send(parseError(err));
    }
});
```

When I logged in, it is successfully creating the session and store in `req.session.user` object. But when I try to access the same object in logout function, it gives me 'undefined' as the value.

logout function,

```
sessionRouter.delete("", ({session}, res) => {
    try{
        const user = session.user; // here session.user is null
        if(user){
            session.destroy(err => {
                if(err) throw (err);

                res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME);
                res.send(user);
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error('Something went wrong');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(422).send(parseError(err));
    }
});

sessionRouter.get("", ({session: {user}}, res) => {
    res.send({user});
});
```

I implemented these functions by referring [this](https://itnext.io/mastering-session-authentication-aa29096f6e22) article and as I understood, values are storing in `req.session.user` object and it could be access in logout function too. But in my case, it is not happening as expected. Is there anything I am doing wrong? How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------

express-session middleware,

```
        app.use(session({
            name: SESS_NAME,
            secret: SESS_SECRET,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            resave: false,
            store: new MongoStore({
                mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
                collection: 'MYsession',
                ttl: parseInt(SESS_LIFETIME)
            }),
            cookie: {
                sameSite: true,
                secure: NODE_ENV === 'production',
                maxAge: parseInt(SESS_LIFETIME)
            }
        }));
```

Comment: Can you access the `req.session.user` object at the other routes rather than the login and the log out route?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not persisting the session anywhere. Like in the memory or in some sort of databases like Redis or MongoDB. If you're using `express` then perhaps check out the `express-session` middleware.

Comment: No it cannot access the ```req.session.user``` in the other routes @AvivLo

Comment: I am using express-session middleware. Once a user logged in, it will store the session details in the mongoDB. I have updated the question with middleware. Can you please check it? @AvivLo

Comment: Try not destructuring the `session` variable but instead use `req.session` directly. Depending on how the session property is implemented it could be a setter in which case you have just given it the wrong `this` value by destructuring it

Comment: I tried in that way too but still the same issue @slebetman

Comment: May we perhaps have a look at your setup for express-session?

Comment: Can you find that session in your mongodb database? Are you sure the session was saved to mongodb?

Comment: Yes, it creates session in mongoDB @slebetman

Comment: Did you set the session somewhere at the front-end? Like the session storage or redux.

Comment: yes im am storing in redux store @AvivLo

Comment: Is it possible to use passportjs instead in your code?